# SPARQL query based on rdf:datatype

Tags: sparql

trying to use EU http://publications.europa.eu/webapi/rdf/sparql service to retrieve names of certain EU directives and regulations based on celex numbers. We need their titles in all EU languages keyed with the relevant ISO_639_1 format (bg, cs, da, de, ...).

We are using this sparql query (e.g. celex 32014R0596 - Market Abuse Regulation):

```
PREFIX cdm: <http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX euvoc: <http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/euvoc#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?ISO_639_1 ?title
WHERE
{
?w cdm:work_id_document "celex:32014R0596"^^xsd:string .
?expr cdm:expression_belongs_to_work ?w .
?expr cdm:expression_uses_language ?lang .
?lang skos:notation ?ISO_639_1 .
?expr cdm:expression_title ?title .
}
ORDER BY ASC(?lang)
```

But we need only ISO_639_1 rows, i.e. based on <skos:notation rdf:datatype="http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/euvoc#ISO_639_1">. The result should look like this:

```
"bg": "Регламент (ЕС) № 596/2014 на Европейския парламент и на Съвета от 16 април 2014 година относно пазарната злоупотреба (Регламент относно пазарната злоупотреба) и за отмяна на Директива 2003/6/ЕО на Европейския парламент и на Съвета и директиви 2003/124/ЕО, 2003/125/ЕО и 2004/72/ЕО на Комисията  текст от значение за ЕИП",
"cs": "Nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) č. 596/2014 ze dne 16. dubna 2014 o zneužívání trhu (nařízení o zneužívání trhu) a o zrušení směrnice Evropského parlamentu a Rady 2003/6/ES a směrnic Komise 2003/124/ES, 2003/125/ES a 2004/72/ES  Text s významem pro EHP"
,
...
...
"sv": "Europaparlamentets och rådets förordning (EU) nr 596/2014 av den 16 april 2014 om marknadsmissbruk (marknadsmissbruksförordning) och om upphävande av Europaparlamentets och rådets direktiv 2003/6/EG och kommissionens direktiv 2003/124/EG, 2003/125/EG och 2004/72/EG  Text av betydelse för EES"
```

Your help will be very welcomed.

Comment: add a filter `FILTER(datatype(?ISO_639_1) = <http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/euvoc#ISO_639_1>)` - to just get the language tag, do `SELECT (str(?ISO_639_1) as ?lang) ...` in the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Uninformeduser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/uninformeduser) the complete working code is as follows:

```
PREFIX cdm: <http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX euvoc: <http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/euvoc#>
SELECT (str(?ISO_639_1) as ?lang) ?title
WHERE
{
?w cdm:work_id_document "celex:32014R0596"^^xsd:string .
?expr cdm:expression_belongs_to_work ?w .
?expr cdm:expression_uses_language ?lang .
?lang skos:notation ?ISO_639_1 .
?expr cdm:expression_title ?title .

FILTER(datatype(?ISO_639_1) = euvoc:ISO_639_1)
}
ORDER BY ASC(?lang)
```